OpenEO Random Forest Classification: No random forest model found for job
I want to classify Sentinel 2 Data by Random Forest Classification. I followed this tutorial (https://open-eo.github.io/openeo-python-client/machine_learning.html) and my batchjob finished without a problem, but when I want to predict a random forest I get this Error: Preflight process graph validation raised: [Internal] No random forest model found for job j-2404221a121941bc96f334a4d96833a2.
Does anybody know why this happens?
from datetime import date
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
#import geemap
#import ee
import openeo 
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal
import numpy as np
import xarray
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

connection = openeo.connect(url="openeo.dataspace.copernicus.eu")
connection.authenticate_oidc()

s2_cube = connection.load_collection(
    "SENTINEL2_L2A",
    temporal_extent=("2023-12-20", "2023-12-22"),
    #temporal_extent=("2024-03-11", "2024-04-11"),
    spatial_extent={
        "west": 48.1643844079999965,
        "south": -18.1685096560000012,
        "east": 49.2115026959999966,
        "north": -17.1647414460000007,
        "crs": "EPSG:4326",
    },
    bands=["B04", "B03", "B02", "B08", "SCL"],
    max_cloud_cover=70,
)

with open(r'C:\Users\Nele\OneDrive\Uni\bachelorarbeit\bachelorarbeit\qgis\final_trainingsgebiete_target.geojson ', 'r') as f:
    feature_collection = json.load(f)

s2_cube_reduced = s2_cube.reduce_dimension(dimension="t", reducer="mean")

predictors = s2_cube_reduced.aggregate_spatial(feature_collection, reducer="mean")

# We can now train a Random Forest model by calling the 
# fit_class_random_forest() method on the predictor vector cube 
# and passing the original target class data:
model = predictors.fit_class_random_forest(
    target=feature_collection,
)
# Save the model as a batch job result asset
# so that we can load it in another job.
model = model.save_ml_model()

training_job = model.create_job()
training_job.start_and_wait()

I got this result for my batchjob:
enter image description here
When I try to execute this block of code I get this error:
predicted = s2_cube_reduced.predict_random_forest(
    model=training_job.job_id,
    dimension="bands"
)

predicted.download("predicted.GTiff")


Preflight process graph validation raised: [Internal] No random forest model found for job j-2404221a121941bc96f334a4d96833a2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OpenEoApiError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-939f68fc7993> in <module>
      4 )
      5 
----> 6 predicted.download("predicted.GTiff")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\datacube.py in download(self, outputfile, format, options, validate)
   2100             format = guess_format(outputfile)
   2101         cube = self._ensure_save_result(format=format, options=options)
-> 2102         return self._connection.download(cube.flat_graph(), outputfile, validate=validate)
   2103 
   2104     def validate(self) -> List[dict]:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\connection.py in download(self, graph, outputfile, timeout, validate)
   1557         pg_with_metadata = self._build_request_with_process_graph(process_graph=graph)
   1558         self._preflight_validation(pg_with_metadata=pg_with_metadata, validate=validate)
-> 1559         response = self.post(
   1560             path="/result",
   1561             json=pg_with_metadata,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\connection.py in post(self, path, json, **kwargs)
    228         :return: response: Response
    229         """
--> 230         return self.request("post", path=path, json=json, allow_redirects=False, **kwargs)
    231 
    232     def delete(self, path: str, **kwargs) -> Response:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\connection.py in request(self, method, path, headers, auth, check_error, expected_status, **kwargs)
    767         try:
    768             # Initial request attempt
--> 769             return _request()
    770         except OpenEoApiError as api_exc:
    771             if api_exc.http_status_code in {401, 403} and api_exc.code == "TokenInvalid":

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\connection.py in _request()
    760         # Do request, but with retry when access token has expired and refresh token is available.
    761         def _request():
--> 762             return super(Connection, self).request(
    763                 method=method, path=path, headers=headers, auth=auth,
    764                 check_error=check_error, expected_status=expected_status, **kwargs,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\connection.py in request(self, method, path, headers, auth, check_error, expected_status, **kwargs)
    166         expected_status = ensure_list(expected_status) if expected_status else []
    167         if check_error and status >= 400 and status not in expected_status:
--> 168             self._raise_api_error(resp)
    169         if expected_status and status not in expected_status:
    170             raise OpenEoRestError("Got status code {s!r} for `{m} {p}` (expected {e!r}) with body {body}".format(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\openeo\rest\connection.py in _raise_api_error(self, response)
    186             error_message = info.get("message")
    187             if error_code and isinstance(error_code, str) and error_message and isinstance(error_message, str):
--> 188                 raise OpenEoApiError(
    189                     http_status_code=status_code,
    190                     code=error_code,

OpenEoApiError: [400] Internal: No random forest model found for job j-2404221a121941bc96f334a4d96833a2 (ref: r-2404226552ef4e1a92f9e5588f827162)


